# Pulling and displaying additional data in datatable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am building a web application using Laravel 5.8. I have started to dive into using JQuery and it's amazing. However, I have not been able to find an answer to my issue. Hoping someone can help.

I have a view named "roles" and it is responsible for showing a list of the security-based roles on the system. On that view, I have a data table displaying that list of roles, date created, and so forth. There is a column for "Permissions" on that data table. Where previously I would put the list of permissions assigned with that role. If you look at my previous code, I was able to achieve that. I have not been able to figure it out with Jquery.

The previous view code:

```
@foreach ($roles as $role)
                    <tr>

                        <td>{{ $role->name }}</td>
                        <td>
                            @if($role->name === "superadmin")
                                <span class="badge badge-primary">All Permissions</span>
                            @else
                                @foreach($role->permissions()->pluck('permission_name') as $permission)
                                    <span class="badge badge-primary">{{ $permission }}</span>
                        @endforeach
                        @endif

                        <td nowrap>@if($role->name != "superadmin")<span class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                              <i class="la la-ellipsis-h"></i>
                            </a>

                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('admin.security.roles.edit',$role->id) }}"><i class="la la-edit"></i> Edit Role</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:delete_role('{{ $role->id }}');"><i class="la la-remove"></i> Delete Role</a>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                        @endif
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
```

The previous controller code:

```php
    public function index()
    {
        $roles = Role::all();
        return view('backend.auth.roles.index')->with('roles', $roles);
    }
```

The current php code:

```php
    public function index()
    {
        $permission = Permission::get();
        if(request()->ajax()) {
            return datatables()->of(Role::all())
                ->addColumn('actions', 'layouts._partials.backend._crud-default')
                ->rawColumns(['actions', 'permissions'])
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->make(true);
        }
        return view('site.backend.auth.roles.index', compact('permission'));
    }
```

The current view code:

```
<!--begin: Datatable -->
            <table class="table table-striped- table-bordered table-hover table-checkable" id="roles_table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Permissions</th>
                    <th>Created</th>
                    <th>Updated</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
            <!--end: Datatable -->
```

The current javascript code:

```
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $('#roles_table').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: "{{ route('admin.security.roles.index') }}",
                    type: 'GET',
                },
                columns: [
                    {data: 'name'},
                    {data: 'permissions'},
                    {data: 'created_at'},
                    {data: 'updated_at'},
                    {data: 'actions', name: 'action', orderable: false},
                ],
                order: [[0, 'name']],
            });
});
```

The error message is showing the obvious and that $role and $permission variables are not present.

Comment: Welcome to the SO club. Would you please show *exact* error message?

Comment: Thanks Yasen!

I am not getting an error message. I simply can not figure out how to pull those additional details and list them within the datatable using jquery/ajax.